# How to format this multi-line string where indentation has to be preserved

Tags: python, unit-testing, indentation, multiline

This is for a to-do list CLI tool in Python. When the items currently in the list are printed to the terminal, the results are automatically formatted to keep indentation consistent for numbers of all digits, e.g.:

```
 8 - Eight
 9 - Nine
10 - Ten
```

I'm writing a test function to check that the indentation is correct, and I want to store the expected output as a multi-line string (see function below).

I want to follow good code formatting practices, and I've seen answers to other questions like this recommend keeping the multi-line string in line with where it's declared, and then stripping or post-processing the string to remove the indentation. e.g.:

```
        expected = """\
                   1 One
                   2 Two
                   3 Three
                   4 Four
                   5 Five
                   6 Six
                   7 Seven
                   8 Eight
                   9 Nine
                  10 Ten
                  11 Eleven
                   ---
                   11 item(s)
                   """
```

However, this won't work in my case since I need 'expected' to have the indentation in a specific format for the test to be useful. At the moment, I've only been able to make the test pass by aligning the string to the far left of the document, which I think is breaking normal Python formatting conventions.

```
    def test_a_long_list(self):
        """Test that we can show a long list going into double figures"""
        with patch(
            "todo.open",
            mock_open(
                read_data="One\nTwo\nThree\nFour\nFive\nSix\nSeven\nEight\nNine\nTen\nEleven"
            ),
        ):
            Handler().list()
        expected = """\
 1 One
 2 Two
 3 Three
 4 Four
 5 Five
 6 Six
 7 Seven
 8 Eight
 9 Nine
10 Ten
11 Eleven
---
11 item(s)
"""
        self.assertPrinted(expected)
```

Comment: it is not breaking python convention, but yes it is "ugly" or "out of line"....

Comment: can you use https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm not sure how the test would still be useful after applying that method? I need to check that in the final output, there is a single space indent for each of the single-digit numbers, but no indent on the two-digit numbers. If I dedent the whole multi-line string, how can I compare that?

Comment: Have you looked at `textwrap.dedent(expected)` for your first `expected` string: it doesn't remove the single spaces before the one-digit numbers, that's not how `dedent` works?

Answer (score 0):

The `textwrap` module has a method called `dedent()` which would achieve this for you.

So modifying the code in the question would be implemented like this:

```py
import textwrap



def test_a_long_list():

    expected = """\
            1 One
            2 Two
            3 Three
            4 Four
            5 Five
            6 Six
            7 Seven
            8 Eight
            9 Nine
            10 Ten
            11 Eleven
            ---
            11 item(s)
            """
    remove_dents = textwrap.dedent(expected)
   
    print(remove_dents)



test_a_long_list()
```

which gives this:

```
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
4 Four
5 Five
6 Six
7 Seven
8 Eight
9 Nine
10 Ten
11 Eleven
---
11 item(s)
```

Comment: Right, but in this case I don't want to remove the indentation. I need to compare the actual result with the expected and the test should only pass if there is a single space before the single digits, so that all text after the number is aligned.